# Gateway is null in Sylius shop

Tags: symfony, gateway, sylius, payum

I started develop a new custom gateway based on skeleton for a Sylius webshop, i would like to access `$this->gateway` in **ConvertPaymentAction** but this is `null`, any idea why? My goal is access payum configuration for my custom gateway what stored in **config.yml** in my shop.

Here the `$this->gateway` is `nul`l always:

```
class ConvertPaymentAction implements ActionInterface
{
    use GatewayAwareTrait;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * @param Convert $request
     */
    public function execute($request)
    {
        RequestNotSupportedException::assertSupports($this, $request);

        /** @var PaymentInterface $payment */
        $payment = $request->getSource();

        $params           = [];
        $params['txid']   = $payment->getNumber();
        $params['type']   = KHEnum::TRANSACTION_TYPE_PAY;
        $params['mid']    = 111111111; //TODO move to config param
        $params['amount'] = $payment->getTotalAmount();
        $params['ccy']    = $payment->getCurrencyCode();
        $params['sign']   = $this->generateSignature(
            $params['mid'],
            $params['txid'],
            $params['type'],
            $params['amount'],
            $params['ccy']
        );

       $request->setResult($params);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a more of the code that you are attempting to do?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: i don't see where you're saying `$this->gateway`

Comment: The action must implement GatewayAwareInterface, https://github.com/Payum/Payum/issues/677#issuecomment-324678441